# Cargar datos por ajax con Jquery y colocar parametros en url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario buscador que quiero que los resultados me devuelva con ajax en un solo sector sin cargar toda la pagina.

Estoy utilizando la funcion `$.get()` de Jquery, pero el problema seria que al devolverme los resultados de la busqueda y querer ir al contenido ya no tendría los resultados al volver atras.

Ya que no coloca los parametros en la url al utilizar `$.get()` de jquery
Como podria implementar una solucion a esto

Comment: la verdad no queda claro lo que planteas. que enlaces de resultado devuelves? Cuando invocas a un servicio este deberia retornar json como respuesta. Se supone que el boton atras del browser no deberias usarlo, sino que deberias tu desde tu aplicacion definir botones de navegacion

Comment: el resultado de $.get() devuelve enlaces que llevan a contenido. como google o cualquier buscador. Cuando voy al contenido y quiero volver ya no esta presente los resultados de la busqueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar los resultados de tu búsqueda en session o en cookies y con esto no pierdes las búsquedas hechas. 
En javascript está sessionStorage, es muy recomendado su uso. 
Más información aquí :
[Almacenando en el cliente: LocalStorage, SessionStorage y Cookies](https://fernetjs.com/2012/12/almacenando-en-el-cliente-localstorage-sessionstorage-y-cookies/)

También puedes usar HTML5 history API. 
Más información aquí:
[Manipulando el historial del navegador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador)

Mucha suerte!

Comment: ya estoy utilizando sessionStorage. Gracias Vanessa ;)

Answer (score 0):

**>>Cuando voy al contenido y quiero volver ya no esta presente los resultados de la busqueda**

Claro porque ajax no interviene en la navegabilidad que el browser implementa, serias tu en el load de la página (ya sea que se ingresa por primera vez o si es producto de un back) que deberias volver a invocar el $.get para volver a cargar los datos.

Sino quieres perder los datos que cargaste mediente el $.get podrias abrir lo link en un popup de esta forma el back no afectaria, podrias usar `window.open()` o sino en el link indicar el `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Habia pensado tambien en abrir en otra ventana, En el buscador de google cuando realizamos una busqueda coloca los terminos de busqueda en la url y cuando vamos al enlace y volvemos la busqueda se mantiene, algo como eso seria lo ideal pero nose como hacerlo

Comment: ok pero google programa para que funcione de esa forma, no es magico. Analiza con el developer tools (accedes con F12, usando la solapa Network) las llamadas que realiza al servidor